# How to search for a DOM element in the Elements panel & highlight it in web page in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am using the latest Chrome & Canary. If I search for a DOM element in the search box in the drawer in dev tools and double click on a result, Chrome switches to the Sources panel and I can't highlight the element in the browser from there. How do I highlight an element from the Sources panel or how do I make search work in the Elements panel?

**Update:**
Highlight the rendered element in the actual webpage in Chrome. I am not talking about highlighting anywhere in dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl-F in Elements panel. That simple.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the magnifier in the dev tools and point it to any rendered element in the webpage and it can highlight the code may be i am not getting your question right

[image]

Comment: Read my comment to Georgiou. I already said what you said in my question. I know how to use search.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that I fully understood your question, but I think that you can highlight anywhere in your main page and by right clicking on it and select 'inspect element' it will open the dev tools and it will highlight the element over there.
Now about the drower, you just search for the elements you want to filter and a list appears with all the elements on your page. If you click on each one it will highlight it back in the Sources Panel (So that is what you wanted in first place I think).

In my opinion it is easier to search for an element through drawer because it will filter all the results for you.

Comment: I want to type a search term, find it in the Elements panel, click on it in the Elements panel and it gets highlighted in the page in the browser. Just like clicking on any element in the Elements panel and the corresponding element in the page is highlighted. I don't want to use the Sources panel at all because it all it does it shows the html at the line. I can't click there and it gets highlighted in the webpage.